# Should i use only w3 standards for production websites?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

i have learned alot of standards in the past few months and now i see that some websites are using features from the working drafts and it got me confused because i checked then few features from standrds and working draft and i could see that standards arent 100% implemented and that working drafts have very good implementation as well almost as standards (transform, animation).

now, on the internet i see websites using non standardized features and it makes me wonder why if its not standard yet and its pretty bleeding edge.. thanks

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only one who can answer this question is you. This ultimately comes down to what you are doing on a per-project basis and the requirements. For example, if you are working on an enterprise software project and there are lots of users that will be running very old machines (think IE10/11) then you will need to make sure you can support those devices with the decisions you make.

If you are working on a project that is only targeting designers and personas that generally have nicer, newer machines and you are not concerned about older devices and browsers, and you think most users will have powerful machines with modern browsers, you can get away with using some much newer stuff.

It is up to us as developers to ask questions about who the intended audience is and let that shape the decisions we make.